# Universal O modules on curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $K$ denote the pro-algebraic group of pointed automorphisms of the formal punctured disk, ie maps $spec(A) \rightarrow K$ are automorphisms of $A[[z]]$ which preserve the augmentation ideal $(z)$.

Associated to a smooth curve $X$ there is a canonical $K$-torsor, $X^{coord} \rightarrow X$, formed by points of $X$ with a choice of local coordinate. As such, if $V$ is a representation of $K$, one obtains a sheaf $V_{X} $ for all $X$ in a manner compatible with étale pull-backs. Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional, so that we obtain a bundle on each curve. Presumably, for $X$ proper, the groups $H^{*} (X, V_{Z})$ only depend on the genus $g$ of $X$, so that we get a bunch of numbers $h^{i, g}(V) $ associated to $V$. Are there any interesting restrictions on these numbers? Eg is the generating function of euler characteristics rational?

PS, there is a similar question with $D$-modules and a larger group ind-scheme in place of $K$.

Comment: Doesn't any finite-dimensional representation factor through the group of automorphisms of $A[z]/z^n$ for some $n$? I believe that implies that any finite-dimensional representation is a summand of some $V_n^{\otimes k}\otimes V_n^{*\otimes m}$ where $V$ is the representation of $K$ on $\mathbb{C}[z]/z^n$. The representation $V_n$ corresponds to the $n$-th jet bundle that admits a filtration with graded pieces $\omega_X^{\otimes i}$ and it might be possible to compute the cohomology of its tensor powers using the fact that the $2$-step extensions $\omega_X^i\to\omega_X^{i+1}[1]$ appearing

Comment: there are induced by the Atiyah class $c_1(\omega_X)\in H^1(\omega_X)$

Comment: Thanks for this excellent point!

Comment: @sasha would u be kind enough to offer a proof of the claim re. any rep being a summand of tensors of the defining rep and its dual? Perhaps it's obvious but eg I think the group is far from reductive... I think it's more likely that any such would have a filtration with associated graded a sum of such, which should be enough for the euler char question at any rate

Comment: Ok I'm now convinced that it's true that any rep has a filtration consisting of reps induced from the quotient K--->G_m, basically bc K is an extension of G_m by a unipotent group. The claim follows easily, thanks @sashaP!